# check if settings is saved in theme option

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to check if setting in theme option was successfully saved (click the save button), below is what I tried

```
<?php
if ($_REQUEST['saved']) {
    echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong>'.$themename.' settings saved for this page.</strong></p></div>';
}
?>
```

but unfortunately, seems not working. Any help please?

Comment: what is the value of ?$_REQUEST['saved'] ?

Comment: just got it from somewhere around the internet (http://aquoid.com/news/tutorials/wordpress-theme-options/w-theme-options-setting-and-retrieving/) :( anyway, whats the proper way of retrieving the on save respond when settings has been saved or how can i check for the return response when settings is saved?

Comment: if(!empty($_REQUEST['saved']))

Answer (score 0):

Try below ::

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['saved']) &&  (null != $_REQUEST['saved'] )) {
    echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong>'.$themename.' settings saved for this page.</strong></p></div>';
} else {
   echo "Some message here";

}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

this works

```
<?php settings_errors(); ?>
```